# Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started a new project named "blog"
and in the terminal i typed $cd blog
and then when i typed $rails server I got the error message 
**Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.**
What should I do?
I tried bundle install but it gives me a fatal error

Comment: did u add gem 'jquery-rails' in your Gemfile and execute bundle install

Comment: How to do that? can you please guide me step by step.

Comment: look up your Gemfile, add `gem 'jquery-rails'` if Gemfile not containe
it, then at your terminial, execute `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

I had installed ruby and rails via rvm, but without the libssl-dev package on ubunut 11.10. To remedy, I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
rvm remove 1.9.3 #or whatever your version of ruby is
rvm cleanup all
rvm install 1.9.3
```

cd to project directory
bundle install

Now I don't seem to be getting the error anymore